# Split string by both newline and full stop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

If I have a string like `test string. something \n else` how would I split the string on both `.` and `\n` characters? I have tried using `re.split(". \n", text)` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I needed to use `re.split("\\.|\n", text)`.